# How to get post data in NextJS with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I wrote a function to get posted form data in a NextJs page. While this works, the req and res parameters aren't typed:

```
const getBody = promisify(bodyParser.urlencoded());

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {

  if (req.method === "POST") {
    await getBody(req, res);
  }

  return {
    props: {
      input: req.body?.input
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried using `req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse` with an interface but the function body won't work:

```
interface ExtendedNextApiRequest extends NextApiRequest {
  body: {
    input: string;
  };
}

export async function getServerSideProps(req: ExtendedNextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {

  if (req.method === "POST") {
    await getBody(req, res);
  }

  return {
    props: {
      input: req.body?.input
    }
  }
}
```

However I get a serialization error:

```
Error: Error serializing `.input` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/my-page".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.
```

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the tsx you're returning for that page or just the form snippet?

Comment: See this page for a full example: https://dev.to/smeijer/handling-post-requests-in-next-js-getserversideprops-50ia

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that you updated your input name to match the server side props: `<input name="input" defaultValue={props.input} />`

Comment: I found that it's best to use GET with forms. Post forms don't seem to be supported, and the hack I have breaks sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using `getServerSideProps` as an API endpoint. `getServerSideProps` is meant to be be used to fetch data from an API endpoint or backend logic and pass it to the function component, so it can not handle post methods. If you want to make an API endpoint, you can make a function in the /pages/api directory. You can strong type that like this:

```
import type { NextApiHandler } from "next";

let handler: NextApiHandler<any> = async (req, res) => {
    // your code goes here
};

export default handler;
```

where the any can be replaced by the type of the api response.

Comment: Do you have an example of posting data to a new page? The original does work for me if I ignore the TS warning.